# Trouble installing uber-rides SDK with pip

Tags: python, uber-api

In fall of 2018, I successfully installed the uber-rides SDK and used it in a python script. However, in June 2019 Uber sent out an email saying the following:

"Uber is upgrading our Developer API program with new access policies for third party applications over the next few weeks.

We’re reaching out to you in advance to let you know that your application will no longer have access to Uber’s public APIs starting June 13th, 2019. Deeplinks into the Uber app will not be affected by this change."

Since receiving this email, I have tried running my script but it says the uber-rides package is not installed. So I tried reinstalling it by entering the following, as Uber's [dev website](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/python) instructs:

`pip install uber-rides`

However, when I enter it, I get the following:

```
Collecting uber-rides
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/a7/a7263ab7a8dfe6c0aa4
35ca86623f6215fcfbf17082dd95c92e22a3b959a/uber_rides-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyyaml (from uber-rides)
```

Then nothing else happens. The console seems to be stuck on this message.

I've done `pip list` to see if uber-rides was already installed but didn't see it in the list.

I also confirmed that my app is still registered with Uber.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

More system info if it's helpful:
-Windows 7 machine
-Python version 3.6.8

Comment: I was able to `pip install uber-rides` without any issues on Linux using Python 3.7.3. How long have you waited for this to complete? Have you tried using another network?

Comment: I let it go for over 2 hours and it just stayed on the "collecting pyyaml" line. However, a coworker had no issue installing it on his machine, which is also Windows. Though unlike me he had never previous installed it.

Comment: What if you `pip install --no-cache-dir uber-rides`?

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot. I guess my next step is to learn a bit more about what caching is for pip.